# Confused about MATLAB visualization

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have a 24 dimensional dataset of 100,000 data points which are mapped onto 2d plane using sammon mapping (a method ro reduce dimensionality and visualize). The scatter plot is shown below! Doesn't look too interesting.[image: Scatter plot of the datapoints].

But when i tilted my screen an looked at the figure, a square array of points appeared. I am not a matlab user and i am confused whether there is some meaning 
 to this for example are the points forming a clusters etc ? or is this just some sorcery.  [image]

Comment: how exactly did you make the plot? what are the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the `scatter` command and change the [scatter properties](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.scatter-properties.html).

```
fig = figure('Color','white');
sc = scatter(y_stacked(:,1), y_stacked(:,2));
sc.Marker = '.';
sc.SizeData = 1;
```

Then, make the figure window as big as possible and/or zoom in to examine your data points more closely.